# WKWebview check if cookie exists

Tags: swift, xcode, post, cookies, wkwebview

I am trying to check if a cookie exists after submitting a POST request. I would like it to be able to provide the cookie values to me once a POST request is complete. I cannot find a way to check if a POST request is completed as well. Thanks for any help in advance!